# ViewDataBinding class for Base Activity

Tags: android, android-databinding

My app has a Toolbar used commonly across all the activities. Hence I'm using a Base Activity to control the oolbar, which all the other activities extend. A common Toolbar layout is included in all separate activity layouts using .  How do I generate/obtain ViewDataBinding object for my Base Activity so that I can access the toolbar and it's child views through it?

Answer (score 0):

If the toolbar is in your BaseActivity you can access it to other class **only if it extends to BaseActivity**  using like this
 **((BaseActivity)this)bindingVarialbleName.toolbarID.currentMethod()**. There maybe **this/activity/context from Base Activity**.